# Weird GPU issue with DVI to HMDI

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors, hdmi, gpu, dvi

I've had my GTX 550ti for around 3 years and never have I experienced the problem.
My computer is fine when I only have my second display in, which is a DVI display.
But when I plugin my main monitor which is dvi to hdmi, the gpu fan spins really fast and the computer shut down.
When I plugin just the main display and boot, the computer POSTS but my main display says there is no cable connected.
is my graphics card failing or do you think it's my cable?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing I'd do is re-seat my card and power molex cable. If that's a no-go, I'd try my DVI==>HDMI **alone** in the other DVI port. If no-go, if you have a known good cable try it.  This card also has an HDMI port too, yes?  Should be able to scounge an HDMI cable to try.